# When should I use the postgresql 10 declarative partitioning function?

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

the [official explain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/ddl-partitioning.html) is:
The benefits will normally be worthwhile only when a table would otherwise be very large. The exact point at which a table will benefit from partitioning depends on the application, although a rule of thumb is that the size of the table should exceed the physical memory of the database server.

When a table is very large?  How to judge a table is very large?
A rule of thumb is that the size of the table should exceed the physical memory of the database server?  What does this sentence mean?

Comment: What exactly is unclear about that sentence? You know how much memory your server has? You know the size of the table? Is it larger? Then it may benefit from this.

Answer (score 2):

The typical use cases for table partitioning (not limited to Postgres) are:

#### Cleanup data

If you need to delete rows from large tables that can be identified by a single partition.

In that case `drop partition` would be a **lot** faster than using `delete`. A typical use case is a range-partitioned table on a timespan (week, month, year)

#### Improve queries

If all (or nearly all) queries you use, contain a condition on the partition key.

A typical use case would be partitioning an "orders" table on e.g. the country and all queries would involve a condition like `where country_code = 'de'` or something similar. Queries **not** including the partitioning key will be however be slower compared to a query on a non-partitioned table.

---

What is "large"? That depends very much on your hardware and system. But I would not consider a table with less 100 million rows "large". Indexing (including partial indexes) can get you a long way in Postgres.

Note that Postgres 10 partitioning is still severely limited compared to e.g. Oracle or SQL Server. One of the biggest limitations is the lack of support for foreign keys and *global* indexes (i.e. a primary key ensuring uniqueness across all partitions). So if you need that, partitioning is not for you.